# SelectList with groups and ungrouped items

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a repository that returns parents and children for two dropdowns in razor views.  When a parent is selected from the parent dropdown, the child dropdown filters for only children of that parent.  When there is no parent selection, the child dropdown has all of the children grouped by parent.  This works well except for having a "Select Child" item at the top of the list and the selected item when there are item groups.

Here is my code for the repository:

```
Children = await results.OrderBy(m => m.ParentId).ThenBy(m => m.Date)
    .Select(m => new SelectListItem {
    Value = m.Id.ToString(),
    Text = m.Date.ToString() + ": " + m.Title.ToString(),
    Group = new SelectListGroup { Name = m.Parent.LastName}
}).ToListAsync();
var tip = new SelectListItem() { Value = null, Text = "Select Child",
    Group = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Default" } };
Children.Insert(0, tip);
return new SelectList(Children, "Value", "Text", null, "Group.Name");
```

This works, but puts the tip in a Default group at the top which is not the end of the world but it seems that html allows some ungrouped options in a select element that also has grouped options.

When I create the tip as a new SelectListItem but without a group:

```
var tip = new SelectListItem() { Value = null, Text = "Select Meeting" };
```

I get a null reference exception in the Razor View code `@Html.DropDownFor()` call.  I'm not sure if the problem is the html helper or if I'm trying to do something that the SelectList server side classes just won't support.

This is the result I'm looking to get, with everything constructed on the server side (controller and view).

```html
<select id="ParentId" name="ParentId" style="width: 100%">
<option value="">Select Child</option>
<optgroup label="Parent 1">
<option value="2">Child 2-1</option>
<option value="3">Child 3-1</option>
<option value="1">Child 1-1</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Parent 2">
<option value="5">Child 2-2</option>
<option value="6">Child 3-2</option>
<option value="4">Child 1-2</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: The data in a HTTP Request/Response body is serialized data and is then deserialized by the Type.   When body is a List<obj> everything works, but when body is a Group which is List<key, List<obj>> it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get a null reference exception in the Razor View code
> @Html.DropDownFor() call. I'm not sure if the problem is the html
> helper or if I'm trying to do something that the SelectList server
> side classes just won't support.

Well, based on your scenario and description, Instead of using `@Html.DropDownFor()` you can use `optgroup`  directly in your view and you should pass the selectList within the loop which manually iterates over the groups and items in your ViewModel and generates the optgroup and option elements accordingly.

I think this way, you have more control over the HTML output, and you can ensure that the optgroup labels are displayed correctly.

In addition, you can also built custom tag helper, however, following approach is more convenient and easy.

Let's have a look in practice, how we can achieve your requirement.

Demo model I have used:

```
public class Meeting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public int? SelectedChildId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var meetings = new List<Meeting>
        {
            new Meeting { Id = 1, Title = "Child 1-1", Date = DateTime.Now, Parent = new Parent { Id = 1, LastName = "Parent 1" } },
            new Meeting { Id = 2, Title = "Child 2-1", Date = DateTime.Now, Parent = new Parent { Id = 1, LastName = "Parent 1" } },
            new Meeting { Id = 3, Title = "Child 3-1", Date = DateTime.Now, Parent = new Parent { Id = 1, LastName = "Parent 1" } },
            new Meeting { Id = 4, Title = "Child 1-2", Date = DateTime.Now, Parent = new Parent { Id = 2, LastName = "Parent 2" } },
            new Meeting { Id = 5, Title = "Child 2-2", Date = DateTime.Now, Parent = new Parent { Id = 2, LastName = "Parent 2" } },
            new Meeting { Id = 6, Title = "Child 3-2", Date = DateTime.Now, Parent = new Parent { Id = 2, LastName = "Parent 2" } }
        };

    var results = meetings.OrderBy(m => m.Parent.Id).ThenBy(m => m.Date)
                  .Select(m => new SelectListItem
                  {
                      Value = m.Id.ToString(),
                      Text = m.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ": " + m.Title,
                      Group = new SelectListGroup { Name = m.Parent?.LastName }
                  }).ToList();

    var tip = new SelectListItem() { Value = "", Text = "Select Child" };
    results.Insert(0, tip);

    var viewModel = new ViewModel
    {
        Children = results
    };

    ViewBag.Children = new SelectList(viewModel.Children, "Value", "Text", "Group.Name");

    return View(viewModel);

}
```

View:

```
@model ProjectName.Models.ViewModel

<select id="ParentId" name="ParentId" style="width: 100%" class="form-control">
    @foreach (var group in Model.Children.GroupBy(c => c.Group?.Name))
    {
        <optgroup label="@group.Key">
            @foreach (var item in group)
            {
                <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
            }
        </optgroup>
    }
</select>
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-8.0#option-group), this might help you know [learn more details about option group in asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-8.0#option-group).

Comment: Ok, this is an interesting point to start from.  However, your code produces different results for me so I'm wondering if we are targeting different netcore versions.  I'm using version 7, and my DataGroupField is left as null with the SelectList constructor as `SelectList(Items, string, string, string)` and the SelectedValue is instead listed as  `Group.Name`.  If I use my syntax for the constructor call, and your view code I get the same error I did in my original question.  When I use your constructor syntax I get a dropdown with a single blank optgroup (optgroup does not have a label).

Comment: The fix with your code is the same, The tip item I add needs to include a group and then the view code works.  The exception is thrown on the GroupBy operation at the `foreach: in` clause when a member of the list has a null group, and I use the constructor for `SelectList()` that correctly assigns the GroupDataField value.

Comment: If you can explain why your code works here, but did not for me as you gave it I'll gladly accept this as the answer because your view code led me to a good workaround.  How are you able to declare the tip without a group and not get an exception, but also have the `dataGroupField` correct in the `SelectList`?

Comment: Well, I am also using .NET 7, however, for this sample version really doesn't matter.  Another point is, in case of null group key, we can assign a default or check check null within the loop. Regarding my post, the main point is to show you how can we implement that using option group in view, rather writing the exact business logic. I'm happy if any of my explanation helps you. In order to wirte the sample for you I have used most of your existing code snippet just modified the view within option group.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @md-farid-uddin-kiron's answer I have manually implemented the select element in my view:

```
<select id="ChildId" name="ChildId" class="w-100">
@foreach(var group in Model.childrenSelect.GroupBy(m => m.Group?.Name))
{
    if(group.Key==null)
    {
        @foreach (var item in group)
        {
            <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
        }
    } else {
        <optgroup label="@group.Key">
            @foreach (var item in group)
            {
                <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
            }
        </optgroup>
    }
}
</select>
```

And in the repository, the tip value to the selectlist enumerable is given a group name with an empty string (which results in the `group.key==null` rather than `group.key==""`).  I don't see any SelectList constructors which take the parameters as given in the other answer referenced, so I'm not sure how that answers code actually worked unless some modification was made and not posted.

Here is the repository now to support the view above, with hardcoded values as used in referenced answer:

```
var testresults = new List<Child>
{
    new Child {Id=1, Title="Child 1-1", Date = DateTime.Now.Date, Parent = new Parent {Id = 1, Code="Project1"} },
    new Child {Id=2, Title="Child 1-2", Date = DateTime.Now.Date, Parent = new Parent {Id = 1, Code="Project1"} },
    new Child {Id=3, Title="Child 1-3", Date = DateTime.Now.Date, Parent = new Parent {Id = 1, Code="Project1"} },
    new Child {Id=4, Title="Child 2-1", Date = DateTime.Now.Date, Parent = new Parent {Id = 2, Code="Project2"} },
    new Child {Id=5, Title="Child 2-2", Date = DateTime.Now.Date, Parent = new Parent {Id = 2, Code="Project2"} },
    new Child {Id=6, Title="Child 2-3", Date = DateTime.Now.Date, Parent = new Parent {Id = 2, Code="Project2"} },
};
Children= testresults.OrderBy(m => m.ProjectId).ThenBy(m => m.Date).Select(m => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = m.Id.ToString(),
    Text = m.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ": " + m.Title.ToString(),
    Group = new SelectListGroup { Name = m.Project.Code }
}).ToList();// Async();
var tip = new SelectListItem() { Value = null, Text = "Select Child",
    Group = new SelectListGroup { Name = "" } };
Children.Insert(0, tip);
return new SelectList(Children, "Value", "Text", null, "Group.Name");
//SelectList(items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue, string dataGroupField);
//This is the constructor for ASP.NET Core 8.0 and 7.0 (perhaps more)
```

The tricky part to this is just the tip text, and wanting that item to appear outside of a group tag in a grouped select list.  If the `SelectListItem` for the tip is made without a group then `DropDownFor` and `GroupBy(x => x.Group?.Name)` throw an exception.  So to get it to work as shown in my question I had to provide a group (`string.Empty`) to the tip item, and then filter them out of an `<optgroup>` in the view code.  Thanks to the previous answer for tipping me off to this method.